# How to generate client code with http basic authentication by cxf wsdl2java

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java

if the wsdl is protected by http basic authentication, how to generate client code by cxf *wsdl2java*, I have read the documentation of *wsdl2java*, but I didn't find any useful option.

Comment: the wsimport tool has a extended option named 'Xauthfile'. is there any way of wsdl2java ?

Answer (score 0):

Basic auth has no impact on generated code. You just need to configure CXF for basic auth on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(webServiceClass);
factory.setWsdlLocation(wsdlLocation);
factory.setUsername(serviceUserName);
factory.setPassword(servicePassword);

T webServiceClassImpl = (T) factory.create();
```